# For what values of $x$ is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over n} 10^{l(n)}(2-x)^n$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is the following series convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {1 \over n} 10^{l(n)}(2-x)^n$$
where $l(n)$ is the number of digits of $n$.

Comment: Hint, $l(n)\sim \log_{10}(n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$n\le10^{l(n)}\le 10n$$
So, for any $N\in\Bbb N$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1n10^{l(n)}|2-x|^n\le 10\sum_{n=1}^N|2-x|^n$$

So the series converges absolutely (and hence, converges) if  $|2-x|<1$, that is, for $1<x<3$.

For $|2-x|\ge 1$

$$\frac1n10^{l(n)}|2-x|^n\ge1\quad\forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Thus, the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Since $l(n)=\lfloor\log n\rfloor+1$, we have
$$\frac 1n10^{l(n)}\le\frac 1n10^{\log n+1}=10,$$
so the general term of the series is $O\bigl((2-x)^n\bigr)$, which converges if and only if $\lvert 2-x\rvert<1$, i.e. $1<x<3$.